# How to apply maskmoney on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, format, currency

I am using maskMoney plugin [here](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/).
I am trying to apply that mask to a div inner text, however i can't make it work.

```
     var_value=$("#b_bouquet_originalvalue").text();
     $("#b_bouquet_originalvalue").text($(this).maskMoney('mask',var_value));
     console.log(var_value);
```

It does not work. any idea?

thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maskMoney will only work on an `<input>` element but it doesn't need to be visible.

You can use a hidden moneyMask `<input>` as a formatter and copy its value to another element (eg div/span) of your choice.

```
$('#currency').maskMoney({prefix:'$'});//hidden by css directive

function set(val, $container) {
    $('#currency').maskMoney('mask', val);
    $container.text($('#currency').val());
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nqw83f7f/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#b_bouquet_originalvalue").maskMoney('mask',yourValue);
```

Comment: this is what i tried but does not work with DIV (works well with input). any idea?

Comment: According to this http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/ it can work only with input !